# sdk can build my cmake project but recipe in bitbake can't

Tags: sdk, yocto

I can build my project with the toolchain which yocto generates for me. but when I wrote a recipe for building and adding it in an image I get this error in do_compile:

```
fatal error: stdio.h: NO such file or directory
```

why this happened and how to fix it?

Comment: You should add your recipe and the complete error log.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was setting compiler Flags in my CMakeList.txt. After deleting all of them, the problem was fixed.